# extracting all tables using tabula

Tags: python, text-extraction, tabula-py

While reading a pdf file using
df = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages=‘all’) —> displays all tables from all pages.

but when converting into a Pandas dataframe using
tables = pd.DataFrame(pdf_file, pages = ‘all’, lattice = ‘True’)[0])—> display only the table on the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The df that you receive from tabula should be in the form of a list.

I also think that if you want to use pandas and tabula together the syntax should be something like below,

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(tabula.read_pdf(pdffile, pages ='all')[0])
```

If you want to utilize what you've gotten from tabula, you can also concatenate it into a single df as shown below

```
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages=‘all’)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

If every table has it's own header, to skip the header for subsequent headers except for first header, try the following:

```
import numpy as np

dfFirstTable = tabula.read_pdf(pdffile)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(tabula.read_pdf(pdffile, pages ='all')), columns=dfFirstTable.columns)
```

Comment: Sorry, I did the same thing, but here, while writing, I forgot to write the complete code.
tables = pd.DataFrame(tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages = 'all', lattice = 'True')[0])

With this code, only the first page's table is displayed.

Comment: I've not tried it yet but I believe you can only receive one table from that line because you are retrieving the first index [0]. Even if you remove the index you would probably get an error if DataFrame doesn't accept a list. If you want all of the tables within one variable df, you will need to concatenate it like shown in the second option above.

Comment: Yes you are right I am getting an error.

Comment: I have the same table continuing on multiple pages and on each page the header is written again.
Is there any way so that it ignores the headers

Comment: Try using numpy. I added it to the answer above. (not tested yet)

Comment: Getting error - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: try use this line instead. dfFirstTable = tabula.read_pdf(pdffile, pages ='all')[0]   ~~possibly the previous way still returns a list

Comment: or you could even add [0] index to the current line and try it out.

Comment: Now the header in the first row is appearing only...means continued header in second row is not appearing